# Bind custom script to a mouse button natively on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

Can I somehow bind executing a script on a mouse button without using third-party apps like autohotkey etc.? For example, I want to automatically rename a file following some rules (which are dictated by my script on any language) by pressing mouse button 4. Can it be done by editing registry or writing custom drivers? Any other way?

Comment: The simple answer is yes.  But how to do it is your challenge.

Comment: Ah... "mouse button 4". This is not a standard mouse, so you'd need to see how the *manufacturer's* drivers work. And drivers are not exactly *native*, but software Windows uses to address devices.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, many mice have MB4, does it mean that driver can work for one mouse and do not for other?

Comment: Yes. *Most* mice have L, R and Scroll buttons *only*. Windows cannot include drivers for all proprietary hardware, but the HW manufacturer can create drivers specific to the HW.